# Read document in firebase collection

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a firestore function which adds data to a collection:

```
func blockUser(userId: String) {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("blocked").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).collection("userBlocked").document(userId).setData([:])
}
```

Works fine, creates a structure like (as expected):

[image]

and in the userBlocked collection its adds a user id which has been blocked like so:

[image]

Im trying to retrieve the userBlocked with the following:

```
    Firestore.firestore().collection("blocked").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).collection("userBlocked").getDocuments{(snapshot,error) in
        guard let snap = snapshot else {
            print("error getting blocked users")
            return
        }
        //var blockedUsers = [User]()
        for document in snap.documents {
            let dict = document
            print("printing blocked user - \(dict)")
        }
    }
```

In the logs im getting:

```
printing blocked user - <FIRQueryDocumentSnapshot: 0x6000015c3610>
```

Im trying to retrieve each blocked user? but can't seem to get each user id, it should be getting back `d8j5fU8rinUcAEZyNZ5qAIzoa1j2`

Comment: Try printing `dict.data()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to write code to get the document data out of the [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/QuerySnapshot) that was delivered to your callback. I suggest starting with the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query).

In your code, `snap` is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/QuerySnapshot), and `document` is a [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/QueryDocumentSnapshot).  You can see from the linked API docs that QueryDocumentSnapshot has a [data()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/QueryDocumentSnapshot#data) method that gets you the document data as a dictionary.

However, you didn't write any fields to the document, so the dictionary will be empty. If you want the ID of the document, you can use [`document.documentID`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentSnapshot.html#documentid).

Comment: thats worked, is there a better way to save the data? as I would only need to save the userid and the dictionary would be empty it would just have the userId

Comment: If this works for you, then there's nothing else to do.